# Where is an Ionic app folder located on Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework

After installed, where can I find the files used by my app?

For example, my app use a sqlite plugin and it generate a database file, "dummy.db". I need to have access to this file but I don't know where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your app on emulator, you may open the emulator via Android Device Monitor and find your app's database using the path 'data/data/your_app_package_name/databases'.